# How do V.I.R.s interact with the Barker?

Tags: steam-park

*This Q/A requires both Steam Park expansions:*
[Play Dirty rulebook](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/7c/48/47-steam-park-play-dirty-rulebook.pdf)
[Robots rulebook](https://www.iello.fr/sites/default/files/2016-11/SteamPark_Robots_EN_Rules.pdf)

---

First, we need to have a definition of "wrong", here. That will define if it's even possible for a V.I.R. to be allowed on the Barker tile.

> When you draw Visitors of the wrong color, put them on the Barker tile
> instead of the Visitors pool.

If you want e.g. a red robot , but you draw a V.I.R., the V.I.R. *can* go to the red spot, but you may not want it to—hence, I think the V.I.R. can be considered "right" or "wrong", per the player's decision.

---

Given that, imagine that there is a V.I.R. on the Barker tile already. I interpret the rules, then, to be that…

1. You may only gain that V.I.R. when you spend only one visitor die for your Attract action.
2. You then can either take another non-V.I.R. Visitor off of the Barker tile, or throw one more into the bag, and draw one.

Correct?

Relevant rules:

> When you Attract Visitors, for each that you spend, you can choose to
> directly take a Visitor from the Barker tile instead of the normal
> action. You immediately gain 1 Dirt token for each Visitor you take
> from the Barker tile.

> When you perform the Attract Visitors action by spending only 1, you
> may choose and take 1 regular Visitor AND one V.I.R. Visitor from the
> Visitors pool and put them both in the bag. If you do, when you draw
> Visitors to complete the action, you must draw out TWO Visitors
> instead of only ONE.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the rules for the wild visitor type that the V.I.R belongs to and the stingy one from the same rules as the barker these types of visitors have their own color and qualify for all rides and can't be considered the wrong type of color.

> When you draw a Stingy Visitor out of the bag, you can place
> them on any Ride regardless of its color, and they will stay
> there until the end of the game giving you money each turn
> like a regular Visitor. But, during the Income Phase, each Stingy
> Visitor only pays you 2 Danari (instead of the normal 3 Danari
> per Visitor). Moreover, during the Dirt Phase, you don’t gain
> any Dirt token for any Stingy Visitors you have in your park.

> When you draw a Wild Visitor out of the bag, you can place them on any Ride, regardless of its
> color, and they will stay there until the end of the game. There are also special rules for how
> to attract them and How they behave (see next page).

Comment: There are bonuses which require visitors of a certain color, and the wild visitors don't satisfy those bonuses.

Comment: @Jessy From my understanding the color is critical to the ride and only visitors that match can count for a ride and the V.I.R. is special and matches all colors.

Comment: What you and I said are true simultaneously.

Comment: @Jessy I think you missed my point which was as far as color matching goes for a cards purpose they match every color even if they don't match it later for a bonus.